# Overlay Background Check

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a custom overlay for `UIImagePickerViewController` in my app.

By default it is set to record video with the tap of a `UIButton`.

If I close the app and then reopen it at a later time the `UIButton` does not start the recording when I tap it.

Any advice on fixing this?

EDIT:

By close the app, I mean press the home button so the app is in the background.

When I reopen the app, by tapping on the icon, the button to start recording video does not work.

Edit 2:

The `UIButton` is in Interface Builder. I have it wired to the action.

Here's my code for that action ...

```
- (IBAction)shutterButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.cameraButton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"]])
    {
        [self.pickerReference takePicture];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self.cameraButton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video"]])
        {
            if (isRecording)
            {
                [self.pickerReference stopVideoCapture];
                NSLog(@"video capture has stopped");

                [self.shutterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shutter_record"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.shutterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shutterHighlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

                isRecording = NO;
                self.settingsButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                self.cameraButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                [self.timer invalidate];
                self.timer = nil;
                self.recordTimeLabel.text = @"00:00:00";
            }
            else
            {
                [self.pickerReference startVideoCapture];
                NSLog(@"video capture has started");

                [self.shutterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shutter_record_stop"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.shutterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shutterHighlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

                isRecording = YES;
                self.settingsButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                self.cameraButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                self.startDate = [NSDate date];
                self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

                self.pickerReference.videoMaximumDuration = 600;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give more details and post code. By "close the app and reopen" do you mean putting it in the background and going back it? An app force-quite should give reproducible results.

Comment: Explain more details of your problem. Your question is too general. How are you creating the button? How are you connecting it to the video recording action? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not decide which action to take by comparing the `image` contained within an `UIImageView`. You do not have any guarantee that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever"]` will return exactly the same object every time. Define a `BOOL` flag like `isCamera`, update it at the same time you update the `imageView`'s `image` and check against this flag instead.

Comment: I actually think that doing this might fix your background issue (probably the UIImage cache gets flushed when you go into background, that's why it stops working). If it doesn't, what exactly does happen when you tap the button after coming back from background? Put a breakpoint or `NSLog()` at the first line of `-(IBAction)shutterButtonPressed:(id)sender` and see if it gets called.